# Как узнать температуру процессора?

Tags: c#

Как узнать температуру процессора?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195112/how-to-get-cpu-temperature/1195150

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть два способа: сложный и кривой. Кривой заключается в использовании WMI, у меня через WMI например ничего не получается. Кто-то говорит что значения есть, но реальности не соответствуют.

Сложный способ - использование драйвера и получение через него MSR инструкцией RDMSR, вероятно через драйвер есть и иные способы.

Comment: а через WMI и не надо пробовать. [там нет температуры ЦП](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101295/msacpi-thermalzonetemperature-class-not-showing-actual-temperature)

Comment: @teran о чем, тащемта, и речь. Но Интернеты пестрят именно этим способом, который особо и не работает.

Comment: У меня почему-то работает... что я не так делаю?

Comment: @Akina Вот уж не знаю. Может дрова на мать такую информацию дают? Приведенный код через WScript в винде не работает определенно.

Comment: НУ WMI-классы сами не появляются из ниоткуда. Тот же Win32_TemperatureProbe, через который тоже можно получить температуру, экспортируется из SMBIOS, а MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature из ACPI Thermal Zone. Нет поддержки - нет и значения,

Comment: @Akina я и говорю что способ кривой. Хотя современные CPU имеют датчики, доступные из кернелмода независимо от SMBIOS/ACPI

Answer (score 1):

> Кривой заключается в использовании WMI, у меня через WMI например ничего не получается. Кто-то говорит что значения есть, но реальности не соответствуют.

```
Set colItems = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\WMI").ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature",,48) 
For Each objItem in colItems 
    Wscript.Echo "CurrentTemperature: " & (objItem.CurrentTemperature-2732)/10
Next
```

Comment: это код на C#??

Comment: Это VBS. А код запроса можно без проблем использовать и из других языков. Делов-то - выбрать правильное пространство имён и не забывать, что возвращается коллекция. А в шарпе, звиняйте, не силён.

Comment: Принцип понятен, спасибо.